# how to upgrade to react native 0.59?

Tags: reactjs, react-native

On [the docs](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/releases/tag/v0.59.0-rc.3) it says:

> To test it, run react-native init RN059 --version react-native@next

but where and how ?

If I type that on my terminal, i get:

```
react-native : The term 'react-native' is not recognized 
as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or 
operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if 
a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ react-native init RN059 --version react-native@next
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (react-nat 
ive:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

So, what to do? :(

Comment: Make sure you have react-native-cli installed

Comment: I did it in the Command Prompt now instead of VS Code terminal :) and it worked

Comment: i'm on 57 now... just great :|

Comment: Maybe just try updating it in NPM. You'll want to read the changelog and check for any broken features manually, but it will work

Comment: but what are the exact steps to have React native 0.59 without having anything installed on the pc but node.js ? 
The documentation lacks this basic explanation. How then a new user could get along? :/
but thanks Kai for suggestions.

Comment: Just run `npm install react-native@next`

Comment: bingo, that worked! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your files as https://github.com/react-native-community/rn-diff-purge/compare/release%2F0.50.0..release%2F0.59.9?diff=unified

Make sure to choose your rn version